# When I run mssql-cli, I get "No module named mssqlcli"

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, python

I just installed mssql-cli with pip,

```
pip3 install mssql-cli
```

Then I try to run `mssql-cli` and I get

```
$ mssql-cli
/usr/bin/python: No module named mssqlcli
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to fix this by [submitting a patch #234 (approved but not yet committed)](https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/pull/234). You'll have to edit the file `~/.local/bin/mssql-cli` and replace

```
python -m mssqlcli.main "$@"
```

With [this line](https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/blob/e21d45cc6bfe048edecfe469f7684e9186b9127f/mssql-cli#L16)

```
( command -v python3 && python3 -m mssqlcli.main "$@" ) || python -m mssqlcli.main "$@"
```